# Mapping properties to array indexes

Tags: c#, arrays, class, properties

I have several properties in a class that appear as such:

```
property1_1 {get;set;}
property1_2 {get;set;}
property1_3 {get;set;}
...
property9_1 {get;set;}
property9_2 {get;set;}
property9_3 {get;set;}
```

These properties need to be mapped to indexes in an array such as:

```
array[0].property1 = property1_1
array[0].property2 = property1_2
array[0].property3 = property1_3
...
array[8].property1 = property9_1
array[8].property2 = property9_2
array[8].property3 = property9_3
```

There are around one hundred of these properties that need to mapped like this and I would rather not have to individually assign them via indexing.  I've looked into using reflection and a couple of other ideas, but none have really "felt" better.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe your best bet is reflection, was there a specific reason you didn't choose reflection? I guess you could write a quick script to auto-gen all of the assignments but I guess that isn't really the point...

Comment: I'm not sure why "feelings" matter very much for the reflection solution. That is the easiest, most direct route.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Since you could combine three properties within a struct or class. If you would then generate an array where the elements are of this type. Or do I see this the wrong way?

Comment: reflection will probably be the way i ultimately go to refactor this.  While I'm not overly concerned about performance, my thinking was having to reflect across all of these properties didn't seem as effecient as just directly assigning them via indexing.  Reducing the lines of code? yes. performing any better? not sure.

Comment: sorry its taken me so long to return to this.  I've gone ahead and implemented reflection to address this issue.  The final reason was simply to remove the preponderance of code.  Measurable performance wasn't impacted at all.  Honestly, I should've just done this from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Could you perhaps try something like this..?

public struct positionStruct
{
  public string location;
  public int coordinateX;
  public int coordinateY;
  public int coordinateZ;
}

```
public class Map
{
   positionStruct [] positionArray = new positionStruct[100];


   public positionStruct this[int index] 
   {
      get { return positionArray[index]; }
      set { positionArray[index] = value; }
   } 
}

//That way you can access the array with Map[index]. Hope this helps
```